# elasticsearch tokenize "H&R Blocks" as "H", "R", "H&R", "Blocks"

Tags: elasticsearch, token, tokenize

I want to preserve the special character in the token, meanwhile still tokenize special characters. Say I have the word

```
"H&R Blocks"
```

I want to tokenize it as

```
"H", "R", "H&R", "Blocks"
```

I read this post http://www.fullscale.co/blog/2013/03/04/preserving_specific_characters_during_tokenizing_in_elasticsearch.html . It explained how to preserve the special character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `word_delimiter` token filter.

[Reading the docs on its use](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/word-delimiter-tokenfilter/) you an set the parameter `preserve_original: true` to do exactly what you want (i.e. "H&R" => `H&R` `H` `R`).

I would set it up like this:

```
"settings" : {
    "analysis" : {
        "filter" : {
            "special_character_spliter" : {
                "type" : "word_delimiter",
                "preserve_original": "true"
            }   
        },
        "analyzer" : {
            "your_analyzer" : {
                "type" : "custom",
                "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                "filter" : ["lowercase", "special_character_spliter"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
"settings" : { 
   "analysis" : {
       "filter" : {
           "blocks_filter" : {
               "type" : "word_delimiter",
               "preserve_original": "true"
           },
          "shingle":{
              "type":"shingle",
              "max_shingle_size":5,
              "min_shingle_size":2,
              "output_unigrams":"true"
           },
           "filter_stop":{
              "type":"stop",
              "enable_position_increments":"false"
           }
       },
       "analyzer" : {
           "blocks_analyzer" : {
               "type" : "custom",
               "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
               "filter" : ["lowercase", "blocks_filter", "shingle"]
           }
       }
   }
},
"mappings" : {
   "type" : {
       "properties" : {
           "company" : {
               "type" : "string",
               "analyzer" : "blocks_analyzer"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: `nGram` doesn't really make much sense. If you did set `min_gram: 1` you would get every letter from `Blocks` => `B` `l` `o` `c` `k` `s` `Bl` `lo` etc...

Comment: You're right - nGram would not be appropriate here. Also, by default, word_delimiters separate tokens based on any alpha-numeric character, so I see now there is no reason to specify "&".

Comment: Can you explain the last part? (About the "blocks" token, I've never used a shingle filter.)

Comment: A shingle filter works the same as an ngram filter, except on words instead of characters. So, if the term was "H&R Blocks Company", and a visitor typed "H&R Blocks", by default "H&R Blocks Company" would not necessarily rise to top of autocomplete. However, with shingle filtering, the exact token "H&R Blocks" is stored in the index. So a query of "H&R Blocks" would receive a higher score, and "H&R Blocks Company" would rise to the top. Shingle filters "enable both exact-match and phrase matching." [reference](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/searching-with-shingles/)

Comment: By the way, enable_position_increments has been removed as of Lucene 4.4, so this won't work "as is" on newer versions of ElasticSearch.