# ElasticSearch "H & R Block" with partial word search

Tags: elasticsearch

The requirements are to be able to search the following terms :

1. "H & R" to find "H & R Block".

I have managed to implement this requirement alone using word_delimiter, as mentionned in this answer [elasticsearch tokenize "H&R Blocks" as "H", "R", "H&R", "Blocks"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223101/elasticsearch-tokenize-hr-blocks-as-h-r-hr-blocks)

Using ruby code :

```
{
  char_filter: {
    strip_punctuation: { type: "mapping", mappings: [".=>", ",=>", "!=>", "?=>"] },
  },
  filter: {
    my_splitter: { 
      type: "word_delimiter", 
      preserve_original: true 
    }
  },
  analyzer: {
    my_analyzer {
      char_filter: %w[strip_punctuation],
      type: "custom",
      tokenizer: "whitespace",
      filter: %w[lowercase asciifolding my_splitter]
    }
  }
}
```

But also, in the same query, we want autocomplete functionality or partial word matching, so

2. "Ser", "Serv", "Servi", "Servic" and "Service" all find "Service" and "Services".

I have managed to implement this requirement alone, using ngram.

```
{
  char_filter: {
    strip_punctuation: { type: "mapping", mappings: [".=>", ",=>", "!=>", "?=>"] }
  },
  analyzer: {
    my_analyzer: {
      char_filter: %w[strip_punctuation],
      tokenizer: "my_ngram",
      filter: %w[lowercase asciifolding]
    }
  },
  tokenizer: {
    my_ngram: {
      type: "nGram",
      min_gram: "3",
      max_gram: "10",
      token_chars: %w[letter digit]
    }
  } 
}
```

I just can't manage to implement them together. When I use ngram, short words are ignored so "H & R" is left out. When I use word_delimiter, partial word searches stop working. Below, my latest attempt at merging both requirements, it results in supporting partial word searches but not "H & R".

```
{
  char_filter: {
    strip_punctuation: { type: "mapping", mappings: [".=>", ",=>", "!=>", "?=>"] }
  },
  filter: {
    my_splitter: {
      type: "word_delimiter",
      preserve_original: true
    }
  },
  analyzer: {
    my_analyzer: {
      char_filter: %w[strip_punctuation],
      type: "custom",
      tokenizer: "my_tokenizer",
      filter: %w[lowercase asciifolding my_splitter]
    }
  },
  tokenizer: {
    my_tokenizer: {
      type: "nGram",
      min_gram: "3",
      max_gram: "10",
      token_chars: %w[letter digit]
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`multi_field`](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) from your mapping to index the same field in multiple ways. You can use your full text search with custom tokenizer on the default field, and create a special indexing for your autocompletion needs.

```
"title": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
        "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
    }
}
```

Your query will need to be slightly different when performing the autocomplete as the field will be `title.raw` instead of just `title`.

Once the field is indexed in all the ways that make sense for your query, you can query the index using a boolean "should" query, matching the tokenized version and the word start query. It is likely that a larger boost should be provided to the first query matching complete words to get the direct hits on top.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. This would not necessarily imply a second anlayzer ? Can a single query search both ? For instance, can I search "H & R Bloc" and return "H & R Block" ?

Comment: I would be concerned about getting too many unrelated hits with such partial words. Stemming usually goes a long way to fix common mistakes, even though that's not exactly what it is intended for. As for autocompletion, it really usually is a different query.

Comment: Although your answer helps a lot, I realize that I have unclearly stated the requirements. I don't need partial word matching only for autocomplete, but also in regular queries. In other words, from one single query, I need to be able to type "H & R" to find "H & R Block", "Service" to find "Services" and "ELE" to find the company "ELE inc" at the top of my results, but any company with "Electricity" in it's name afterwards. I will update my question to express this.